# In Scala, need to compare possibly null value to search string which might be "null"

Tags: scala

I'm relatively new to Scala and want to find a cleaner way of doing this:

I currently have some function:

```
def someFunction(someSearchString: String, someSet: Set[SomeType]): Set[Blah] = 
   someSet.collect {
      case SomeItem(x, y, z) 
         if z.getOrElse("null") == someSearchString => // etc.
```

This works, but in my opinion, it looks kind of messy to have to keep doing `.getOrElse("null")` since we have something similar all throughout this class due to the code base we are interfacing with. It should be considered a match if someSearchString is "null" and z is not defined. We can't change someSearchString to be null instead of "null" unfortunately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that if `someSearchString` is "null" then it must match if `z` is `Some("null")` as well as if `z` is `None`?

Comment: Yes, if I'm understanding you correctly, then you are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution isn't a bad one.

Here's a different approach, but it's only useful if there is some significant difference between the way the two conditions are processed.

```
def someFunction(someSearchString: String, someSet: Set[SomeType]): Set[Blah] = 
  someSet.collect {
    case SomeItem(x, y, Some(`someSearchString`)) => // etc.
    case SomeItem(x, y, None)
      if someSearchString == "null" => // etc.
  }
```

Comment: It is sophisticated.